# basic popen3 syntax in ruby

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, popen

Are there any differences between the following two uses of `popen3`?

```
html = ''
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("curl #{url}")
html << stdout.read
```

and

```
html = ''
Open3.popen3("curl #{url}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  result << stdout.read
end
```

I'm wondering if the second syntax causes some thread to block. I'm fairly new to asynchronous code so any insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first form you should explicitly close `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: Perhaps not closing those streams can cause problems if the first syntax is used in a loop?

Comment: I think there will be problem if you're opening many streams in a loop. I suggest you to pick out everything related to popen3, test it and then inject to your main project.

Comment: Good idea. I wonder if the streams in the second form above are closed after the block?

Comment: Yes, block will close stream automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are experiencing a blocking behavior is because you did not close stdin to the program (curl) you opened via `popen3` -- so curl is still waiting for your input.

You should close stdin explicitly via `stdin.close` after you are done sending data to the program, otherwise it will keep expecting input on stdin, and `popen3` will hang.

```
 stdin.close    # always close your stdin after you are done sending commands/data
                # or popen3 will appear to hang
```